# Intuitive understanding of Word2Vec transform

Tags: word2vec

My understanding of the Word2Vec transform procedure is that AFTER using a large corpus of sentences to train the model, the model will learn the vector spaces and we can use the word vectors to transform a sentence of *k* words to a single vector with a length of *D*, where *D* is the number of dimensions. The *k* words will be transformed into a *k * V* one-hot encoded matrix, where *V* is the size of the vocabulary. Then it times the input hidden weight (*V * D*). The result is a *k * V* matrix. If we average over the *k* elements in a column, we can obtain the final vector with the length of *D*.

My question is what does it really mean with the final vector with the length of *D*, intuitively.  Would something get removed when you average over the *k* rows? Also, sentences like "Babies love carrots." and "carrots love babies" will be transformed into the same vector, but the two sentences are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Word2Vec does *not* "transform a sentence of k words to a single vector with a length of D".

There are other algorithms for converting sentences/texts of multiple words to a single vector.

But word2vec uses large collections of text to learn vectors for individual words. (It does this by optimizing some initially-random word-vectors to get ever-better at predicting nearby neighboring words.)

At then end, each word has a vector - not each sentence.

(You could of course average a bunch of word-vectors together to get a vector for that longer run-of-words, and that's an OK baseline approach for some simple tasks. But that's a downstream application of word2vec, and relatively crude.)

Comment: Thanks, @gojomo for answering this question. I think I am a bit inaccurate about my question. What I meant was that AFTER word2vec uses large collections of text to learn vectors for individual words, we can use the learned word vectors to transform some sentences. But what does that transform mean???

Comment: How do you propose using the learned word vectors to transform some sentences? What that transformation means will depend on what transformation you choose. The baseline approach I mentioned, averaging all the word-vectors together, gives you one vector, of the same dimensionality of the words, for the group-of-words. It's like a word-vector for the whole text. It may often be helpful on some tasks, & vaguely comparable to the individual word-vectors to aid in intepretability, but is still a pretty weak way to get a vector from a text, as it has no understanding of word-order/grammar/etc.

Comment: makes sense. I am trying to match some sentences to some anchor words. I guess the averaging approach would actually make sense for my project. Thank you so much for discussing this with me!